# Select all values from last date that is shared between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’ve got a Postgresql table with counts for countries over time. Not every country has a count for each date, and some have NULL values. I’d like to get the counts for each country **up to the last date every country has data for**, excluding NULL values.

I made a [DB Fiddle with example data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aBqu4uSj5Axq2mN3uJMXTz/1).

Example:

```
country date        count  id
Germany 2020-05-25  10     1
Germany 2020-05-26  11     2
Germany 2020-05-27  12     3
Germany 2020-05-28  13     4
Italy   2020-05-25  20     5
Italy   2020-05-26  21     6
Italy   2020-05-27  22     7
Italy   2020-05-28  23     8
France  2020-05-25  30     9
France  2020-05-26  31     10
France  2020-05-27  NULL   11
```

I’d like to get back the following:

```
country date        count  id
Germany 2020-05-25  10     1
Germany 2020-05-26  11     2
Italy   2020-05-25  20     5
Italy   2020-05-26  21     6
France  2020-05-25  30     9
France  2020-05-26  31     10
```

I’ve searched, but I’m relatively new to SQL and don’t seem to know what keywords to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to count the number of rows with dates and then compare to the number of countries:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, COUNT(count) over (partition by date) as num_countries_on_date
      FROM countries c
     ) c
WHERE num_countries_on_date = (SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT c2.country) FROM countries c2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=07a8793aa75ff9629c0a31eb57fc11eb) is a db<>fiddle.

If you wanted to generate data for a range of dates -- sort of the opposite problem -- you could use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows, a `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the data, and `COALESCE()` to turn `NULL` to `0`:

```
SELECT c.country, d.date, coalesce(co.count, 0) as count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT country FROM countries) c CROSS JOIN
     generate_series('2020-05-26'::date, '2020-05-27'::date, interval '1 day') d(date) LEFT JOIN
     countries co
     ON co.country = c.country AND co.date = d.date;
```